# Python3 does not have line_profile?

Tags: python-3.x, profile

There is no [line_profile](https://pythonhosted.org/line_profiler/) in Python 3. Is there any alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pprofile`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pprofile) is the alternative that was inspired by `line_profiler` and, according to the `PyPI`, it supports python-3.x. Besides, it is pure-python.